# Selecting the name and the number of albums from a database

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following database (http://blog.xojo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/ChinookDatabaseSchema1.1.png) and I would like to select the name of the artist and the number of albums the artist has recorded, but every time i run the code, it displays the 1st name and the total number of albums.

This is my code:

```
SELECT Name, count(*)
FROM album
INNER JOIN artist
ON album.ArtistId = artist.ArtistId;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Group By`

```
SELECT Name, count(*)
FROM album
INNER JOIN artist ON album.ArtistId = artist.ArtistId;
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Thank you so much.